# Make Textbox always with underscores overriden only with input characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

As all of us know, some sites use input fields for few characters like PIN code: _ _ _ _

that users supposed to fill with numbers or other characters. 
I'm looking for way to implement this, with:

1. on page load should be _ _ _ _ in the textbox (it's simple).
2. don't have to select or/and delete existing characters, just overrite by keyboard pressing.
3. if number char deleted, the _ sign will return (prevent blank spaces)

I tried str.replace(/\s/g,'_') and more things like this but till now not solved the problem. Didn't find simple (and working) solution here or somewhere else..

Comment: maybe handle the keypress event so on every character entry you can massage the input

Comment: Masked inputs, plenty of libraries out there

Comment: What does "tb" means ? No SMS words please.

Comment: Text Box of course.. Thanks! fixing now..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can use a masked input lib, such as [jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)

It's pretty simple to use and very customizable.
[Here's an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooXdYy) of what you want to do

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="masked" placeholder="____">
```

**JS**

```
$("#masked").mask("9999");
```